# React-idle-timer session does expire if i leave screen

Tags: reactjs, session

I am using react idle timer. My session only expires if screen is opened if I close that screen it does not expire after the given time. here is my Code

```
const {getLastActiveTime } = useIdleTimer({
        timeout: 1000 * 60 * SESSION_IDEL_MINUTES,
        onIdle: handleOnIdle,
        debounce: 500,
    })
const handleOnIdle = (event ) => {
        console.log('user is idle', event)
        console.log('last active', getLastActiveTime())
        localStorage.removeItem("HotelCode");
        setIsLogin(false);
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Dev, did you manage to fix the issue? I am facing the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting SESSION_IDEL_MINUTES from?

Also, "debounce" is used for "onAction" ..not "onIdle"